# How do I setState within React's recompose's lifecycle method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, recompose

I am using recompose in my React project
https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/

It's a great library. I'm using the `compose` utility as a container component that passes state down as props to the presentational component like so:

```
const enhance = compose(
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      myCall
        .getResponse([productId])
        .then(products => {
          setIsReady(true);
        });
    },
  }),
  withState('isAvailable', 'setIsAvailable', false),
  withState('isReady', 'setIsReady', false),
  mapProps(({
    setIsAvailable,
    setIsReady,
    ...state,
  }) => ({
    onLogoutTouchTap: () => {
      ...
```

Note the `setIsReady(true)` call within `componentDidMount`. This is what I want to do, however lifecycle/componentDidMount doesn't have access to `setIsReady`. How can I accomplish my intended result of updating state from `componentDidMount` with recompose?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well I found out if you move the `lifecycle` method after the `withState` methods, you have access to the setters by accessing `this.props.setterFunction`. In my case, here is the solution I was looking for:

```
const enhance = compose(
  withState('isAvailable', 'setIsAvailable', false),
  withState('isReady', 'setIsReady', false),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      myCall
        .getResponse([productId])
        .then(products => {
          this.props.setIsReady(true);
        });
    },
  }),
  mapProps(({
    setIsAvailable,
    setIsReady,
    ...state,
  }) => ({
    onLogoutTouchTap: () => {
      ...
```